# What is the best way to append data from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

At the moment i am using `JSON` as a result of `AJAX` and dynamically create all new DOM elements which i need. But here I was thinking - is it right? For example if i need to create a `<table>` of data is is better to build it with JS or generate it on the server and just append result to the page?

**UPDATE**
Now i do like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(result){var table = jQuery('<table/>').append([jQuery('<td/>.....
```

But also can simply like this:

```
jQuery.get(URL, function(result){jQuery('body').append(result);}.......
```

Comment: you can use a templating engine then you can use javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  What are your own criteria for success?

Comment: For the table example, it really depends. Will it be a db query? Will your table have a script applied (sortable, datatables, etc)? Have a search? These kind of 'add-ons' that will show you if you need to go for server or ajax. I like client-side more because you leave to your host to process the query and display. And not to the client's browser to download the additional data then process and create the DOM elements. But if the table has search and pagination, it's better to use ajax to not force you to make a `*` query with no limit, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is really no one answer to your question - it all depends on your software type, expected loads, etc.

clearly, moving "rendering" to client side, would reduce the amount of code transmitted between server and client and also less server resources would be used on generate html code (clearly, we are talking about miniature difference). However, it might become really important, if you are talking about thousands of online visitors.

But if you were having thousands of visitors, you would not have asked such question :) So, I guess, you should format all stuff on Server side and void bothering about this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong. It all depends on what suits you best. I personally find JSON to be a good all-purpose format. What you should never do is return the data as HTML to be appended. Try to keep your data free of any structuring that belongs to the presentation layer.

For more information, have a read on [Model-View-Controller](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the result. With small results it would make no difference.

But if you are sending a lot of rows for a table a JSON response would be much more efficient than the actual table html code.

Using a template engine like @Arun P Johny said in his comment is a good way to process a JSON  result set.

Check underscore templates http://underscorejs.org/#template